# WebServiceHost not working after disabling anonymous authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, rest, wcf

I have an rest wcf service integrated with asp.net and deployed in IIS. This is working fine when anonymous authentication is enabled. When it's disabled it's throwing 401 error when i use the rest api call in postman. In IIS anonymous authentication and Forms authentication are enabled. Now i disabled Anonymous and Forms and enabled windows authentication only.
My code is below:

```
public class SampleWebServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
    {
        private Type ContractServiceType;
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public SampleWebServiceHostFactory(Type contractServiceType):base()
        {            
            ContractServiceType = contractServiceType;
        }

        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {            
            WebServiceHost host = (WebServiceHost)base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType,baseAddresses);


            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            WebHttpBinding mybinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            mybinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            mybinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            mybinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedRequest;
            mybinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 1204;
            mybinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
            mybinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
            mybinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
            mybinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
            mybinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(4,0,0);
            mybinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(4,0,0);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(ContractServiceType, mybinding, "");
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new RestServiceBehavior());
            log.Info("Testing1");
            return host;
        }
    }
```

the below code in config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client/>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have enabled logging in Global.asax to see where issue occurs. After the Session_Start method fired i see the log line "Testing1" in the above code. After that no logging and it threw 401 error in postman and keep on asking for username and password when i use the url in in browser.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have already set up the configuration in the constructor of the WebServiceHostFactory, It is unnecessary to configure it in the configuration file separately.

```
      <webHttpBinding>
    <binding receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

I suggest you refer to the below configuration for Windows Authentication.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="rest" contract="WcfService3.IService1" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="rest">
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows">
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

After that, disable other authentication modes in IIS. We need to provide a pair of windows credentials while calling the service.
[image]
The credential is actually the windows account on the server-side, which enables us to access the website.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.